resize widgets following with the window
profile page is 1240px per 700, I am placing widgets everything works fine until I resize I would like to know if there is a way to when we resize the window to full screen the widgets, like instead of staying in their positions they resize with the window too,
    photo_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=window, width=120, height=120, corner_radius=10)
    photo_frame.place(x = 1140, y = 0)

is it possible that when I resize to full screen it follows the position, I don't know If I am explaning right, but instead of satying at the previous coordeniates it goes to the right top edge of the resized window
I want to get my widgets to all dynamically resize as the window resizes

Try using pack with expand and fill instead of place, e.g. photo_frame.pack(expand=True, fill='both').

I agree with @JRiggles: place is almost always the least preferable tool to use grid or pack makes it easier to create a responsive GUI.
